# Segmentation fault in DAG

Tags: segmentation-fault, abstract-syntax-tree, directed-acyclic-graphs, calloc, static-allocation

How to Fix this Segmentation fault in, I have tried Some alternatives but still it's not working.

```
strcpy(temp->label,'\0');
strcpy(temp->target,'\0');
```

Comment: struct Listnode
{
char data[50];
int leader,block,u_goto,c_goto; 
struct Listnode *next;
char label[10],target[10];
}*temp,*cur,*first=NULL,*last=NULL,*cur1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not correct

```
strcpy(temp->label,'\0');
```

strcpy wants a pointer to a string, you mean

```
 strcpy(temp->label,"\0");
```

or even simpler

```
 strcpy(temp->label,"");
```

this assumes that temp->lable has memory assigned to it in some way

EDIT: this is the most efficient way

```
 temp->label[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank You so Much Sir , It worked . Because of you I'm able to fix this Fault.